# python script to open excel workbook, and change the name of the first worksheet and execute stored proc

Tags: python

i have this python script that's supposed to open an excel workbook from directory and then change the name of the first worksheet and then run a stored procedure on the first worksheet and the subsequent worksheet.
When I run the script it gives me an error - 'str' object attribute 'title' is read-only. Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

```
import os
import pyodbc
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook


dirList = os.listdir("""\\Raw_Data\\HSRx""")

#database connection
#loop through excel workbooks
#loop through excel sheets in each workbook
#run stored proc on each worksheet
#close files and disconnect to sql server
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQLServer};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydb;UID=myname;PWD=mypwd')
cursor = conn.cursor()

for n in dirList:
    path =os.path.join("""\\Raw_Data\\HSRx""",n)
    workbook = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(path)
    worksheets = workbook.get_sheet_names()
    sheet = ['None','None']
    i = 0
    print n
    for worksheet in worksheets:
        worksheet.title = "Sheetone"
        sheet[i] = "Sheetone"
        i += 1
        print worksheet
    cursor.execute("""exec SP_IMPORT_HSRx_Ins ?, ?, ?""",n,sheet[0],sheet[1])
    cursor.commit()


conn.close()
```

Here is the traceback:

```
CS NOV20 12.xlsx Traceback (most recent call): 
  File "HSRXRecons.py", line 25, in <module> worksheet.title = "Sheetone" 
AttributeError: 'str' object attribute 'title' is read-only
```

Comment: Please, place full traceback here.

Comment: CS NOV20 12.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call):
  File "HSRXRecons.py", line 25, in <module>
     worksheet.title = "Sheetone"
AttributeError: 'str' object attribute 'title' is read-only

Answer (score 3):

`worksheet` is a string, because `get_sheet_names()` returns a list of strings.  You cannot assign attributes to strings.

```
>>> 'Sheet1'.title = 'Sheetone'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object attribute 'title' is read-only
```

To change the title pass the sheet name to `get_sheet_by_name`:

```
workbook.get_sheet_by_name(worksheet).title = "Sheetone"
```